# Knobs offset after DrawPane zooming

Tags: smartgwt

I create DrawRect

```
    DrawRect drawRect = new DrawRect();
    drawRect.setDrawPane(pane);
    drawRect.setLeft(x-25);
    drawRect.setTop(y-25);
    drawRect.setWidth(50);
    drawRect.setHeight(50);
    drawRect.setFillColor("#FF0000");
    drawRect.setFillOpacity(0.2f);

    drawRect.setCanDrag(true);
    drawRect.setKnobs(KnobType.RESIZE);

    drawRect.draw();
```

and knobs work good. But when I change zoom on DrawPane

```
     zoomLevel = pane.getZoomLevel();
     pane.zoom(zoomLevel+0.001f);
```

I can not use the knobs because they shift.
It looks like this
http://clip2net.com/s/4XXJmY

Comment: Added a [thread in SmartGWT](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=26378) forum on this

Comment: This has been fixed and now knobs are working after a zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be an issue in SmartGWT, or certain fixes done in SmartClient are not moved to SmartGWT yet.
There was a previous [**issue**](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=25604&highlight=DrawPane+zooming) that they fixed on mouse events, but still knobs are not working.

I couldn't use knobs after a zoom either, with smartgwt-4.0d/LGPL/2013-04-25 and GWT 2.4.0.
I've even tried `drawRect.showKnobs(KnobType.RESIZE);` inside `DrawHandler.onDraw()` which didn't change the behavior.

Both `drawRect.getKnobs()` and `drawRect.getResizeKnobPoints()` during zoom trigger (button click handler/etc.) had proper values (they didn't change before/after zoom).

During zoom trigger `DrawPane.getDrawItems()` showed separate `DrawItem` instances for knobs both before and after zoom.

Used following to see how mouse events were affected with zoom.
They seemed to work the same before/after zoom inside the highlighted area in given image.

```
final Label label = new Label();
label.setWidth100();
label.setHeight(20);
label.setContents("event details");

drawRect.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.drawing.events.ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.drawing.events.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
        label.setContents("mouse click: " + clickEvent.toDebugString() + "; " + new Date().getTime());
    }
});
drawRect.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {
    public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent mouseMoveEvent) {
        label.setContents("mouse move: " + mouseMoveEvent.toDebugString() + "; " + new Date().getTime());
    }
});
```

[image]

Probably a good idea to post in [SmartClient/SmartGWT forum](http://forums.smartclient.com/forumdisplay.php?f=14).

Somewhat related - http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=21345&highlight=DrawPane+zooming